# Bluetooth is suddenly switched off and not active anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, ubuntu-20.04

Suddenly my Bluetooth is switched off, and I did almost everything I know to make it active without any response!

Check this out! [Screenshot of my Bluetooth connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOnoD.png)

Here is some info:

> systemctl | grep -i blue

output:

```
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d14-1\x2d14:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device        loaded active     plugged      /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0     
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                               loaded active     plugged      /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0   
  bluetooth.service                                                                         loaded active     running      Bluetooth service   
  bluetooth.target                                                                          loaded active     active       Bluetooth
```

> rfkill list

output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
             Soft blocked: no
             Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
             Soft blocked: no
             Hard blocked: no
```

> lsusb

output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:565a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> systemctl status bluetooth.service

output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-06-15 14:17:57 CEST; 22min ago
      Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
      Main PID: 94071 (Bluetooth)
      Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18883)
      Memory: 1.2M
      CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
              └─94071 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

  Jun 15 14:17:57 hitch-Inspiron-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
  Jun 15 14:17:57 hitch-Inspiron-7590 bluetoothd[94071]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
  Jun 15 14:17:57 hitch-Inspiron-7590 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
  Jun 15 14:17:57 hitch-Inspiron-7590 bluetoothd[94071]: Starting SDP server
  Jun 15 14:17:57 hitch-Inspiron-7590 bluetoothd[94071]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

I also tried to disable and enable bluetooth.service

> sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
>
> sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service

I also reinstalled bluetooth:

> sudo apt remove blueman
>
> sudo apt install blueman

Then I run:

> blueman-manager

output:

```
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 14.45.44 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 14.45.44 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

So, now I am puzzled. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem as you but I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the correct site for this question. Maybe you can post the same question over on https://superuser.com/?

Comment: Hey Frost! Thanks for your reply! I thought the Ubuntu tag is for everything related to Ubuntu! I am new here, so I am trying to understand how it works!. Back to my question and your problem, actually, for some reason, it worked for me! What I did else? I installed the newest Linux framework! I didn't work after the first reboot! but next day It did work? reason? I have no clue :)

Comment: I have also noticed that sometimes it seems to work after a reboot, but then at some later point it won't work anymore. I honestly have no clue going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found a solution where it was suggested to:

1. Disable bluetooth in your UEFI / BIOS settings
2. Reboot
3. Enable bluetooth again in your UEFI / BIOS settings
4. Reboot

This worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

I found the solution here:
https://superuser.com/a/1451102/121441

Which on their turn found their solution here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348005

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, I did restart and turn off Bluetooth in UEFI/BIOS and, then I restarted again and turned Bluetooth on in the UEFI/BIOS but it didn't solve the problem.
I then restarted using Kernel before the last update (last Kernel was 5.15.0-73 but I selected 5.15.0-72), well everything went fine and Bluetooth started to work again. So I thought "it is Kernel related thing" so I wanted to report bug and to do so I restarted to that I thought to be the "bug" Kernel, but for my surprise the Bluetooth did work in that Kernel this time!
So it wasn't the Kernel.
I don't know what was the problem, but switching between Kernels did seems do the trick and fix it.
This worked for me so I think maybe it work for some others too.

Edit: Well, next time I turn on my Laptop, Bluetooth didn't work again, so restarted to 5.15.0-72 fixed it again, so it seems to be Kernel things after all.

Edit again: Well seems to be my new norm to fight with the Bluetooth. Never had a problem before, just suddenly now when I start the laptop, Blueman won't find any device.
I tried install the newest Kernel 5.19.0-43 and when restart Bluetooth did work. I will see tomorrow if it is just temporary until next reboot or permanent...